# HTML/CSS Not moving to the left

Tags: html, css, text, navigation, navbar

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Formats the Navigation bar */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}


/* Formats the page title */

nav p {
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 55px;
  float: left;
}


/* formats the navlinks to the left */

nav ul {
  float: left;
}


/* formats the navlinks to left */

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}


/* formats the text in the list for nav bar */

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 22px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* styles the drop down */

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
}


/* Displays when hovered */

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 8px 14px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Teams</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Third</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fourth</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.php">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hi guys i cant seem to understand whats going on. I've tried everything i can but i can get the text to align to the left like in default html. I have a home page that looks like this:

```
<?php include ("navBar.php") ?>
home
```

Thats it and for some reason "home" ends up half way across the page, i have included the defaults margin and padding to the top of the stylesheet but its not working. Any help will be great thanks.

Comment: Your snippet loads your links left-aligned for me (Google Chrome 67.) Is this not how it's supposed to display? https://i.imgur.com/Wb7VuVi.png

Answer (score 0):

I see there is nav ul li a class, and it has a display value block. Try doing it to inline-block instead and see if it works.